# What is the purpose of seed in Sql function RAND()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am aware that Rand() is used to generate a random number less than 1 and greater than 0. 
if you supply seed , it will generate same value for same seed in the same connection everytime you execute it.
Also `select RAND(1),RAND()` both would always give you same resultset everytime you execute it in same connection.

But how is seed useful?

Comment: Sometimes you need to test your algorithms, dealing with / based on random numbers - using specific seed you can have always same sequence and thereby repeatable result values. Or, in production code, you again can create repeatable cases - sometimes required in simulations.

Comment: It is not just in the same connection, `RAND(1)` will always return the same value. It allows you to get a repeatable random number so you can run the same tests multiple times with consistent results. Another great use is when you want a random number that is different for every row, then you can use `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` to ensure a different seed is passed for every row.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit implicit, but is well-documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx):

> Repetitive calls of RAND() with the same seed value return the same results.
>
> For one connection, if RAND() is called with a specified seed value, **all subsequent calls of RAND() produce results based on the seeded RAND() call**. For example, the following query will always return the same sequence of numbers.
>
> `SELECT RAND(100), RAND(), RAND()`

So, `SELECT RAND(1), RAND()` will return the same numbers and `SELECT RAND(), RAND()` won't.

Comment: Yes, yes but what is the use of this? I can find many uses for Rand() because it generates random number but what use is seed? In what situation would you ever need seed?

Comment: I probably won't find better examples for certain seed than Piskvor did. Please check out his answer.

Answer (score 2):

A set of numbers which have been randomly generated *once*, but which remains the same over each invocation, is useful in cases where you need to share this specific set. In other words, the seed maps deterministically to a set of normally-distributed numbers; if all the users of the seed are using the same PRNG, they will receive the same (infinite) set of pseudorandom numbers without the need for further synchronization.

An example use case: "this is a randomly shuffled deck of cards, see how well your AIs can play it - in repeated matches with the same deck."

Or "for this Minecraft competition, you will use the world generated with seed #123456789, and do something awesome with it."

See also this: http://rednuht.org/genetic_cars_2/ there's a "seed" field, which will generate the same set of tracks, which is useful for testing various populations on the same terrain. Here, you can see the effect of a shared seed interactively.

Comment: Or "the program fails on seed #1234, please find the bug".